# Delphi Google Maps SDK for iOS

Tags: ios, google-maps, delphi, delphi-xe5, delphi-xe4

i am new to iOS platform, i was trying to use google maps for an iOS application. i have found sample in XE5
\RAD Studio\12.0\Samples\MobileCodeSnippets\Location
This works but how to i hide the controls on the google maps.

**A)**How to disable google default controls using URL
links : To disable the default controls is
http://www.w3schools.com/googleAPI/google_maps_controls.asp

I have tried like this

```
const
LGoogleMapsURL: String = 'https://maps.google.com/maps?q=%s,%s&output=embed';
 var
  sLatitude ,sLongitude : string;
begin
    sLatitude := 'Latitude: ' + '15.4989';
    sLongitude := 'Longitude: ' + '73.8278';
    WebBrowser1.Navigate(Format(LGoogleMapsURL, [sLatitude, sLongitude]));
 end;
```

but how do i use ***disableDefaultUI:true*** to remove the default control and on the maps?
i had tried something like this

```
maps.google.com/maps?z=12&t=m&q=loc:38.9419&style=feature:all|element:labels|visibility:off
```

no controls
[image]

with controls
[image]

**B)** Goodle SDK for Delphi XE4/XE5 or components for Google maps for iOS in Delphi
can any tell me how to use google maps in iOS using google maps API?
like https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/

i have found [iOS components](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dpfdelphiios/?source=directory) but they have apple maps

Answer (score 1):

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/xml?radius=50000&query=%@&sensor=true&key=UseYourOwnKey
```

Use this google Api. Pass your location in query in this api. You will get top 20 results related to your search location. No need to pass latitude and longitude. Just pass the location name.